# How is the search snippet and meta "description" of a post determined?

Tags: elasticsearch

Wen you search in stackoverflow, in most cases a search snippet (first 40 words or so of a post / question) is shown.  In some cases, more text is shown and this text includes the search terms.  Both blocks of text are ending with ellipsis symbol.

If you look at the meta tag "description" or "og:description", a similar text is included, thus allowing Google to index correctly.

My questions:

- What search engine is stackoverflow using (elastic search / Lucene) ?
- How and when is the search snippet determined (in realtime during search action or when saving a post / question ?)
- How and when is the meta-description determined.

I ask these questions because I want to prevent that I start coding an algorithm to determine the first 40 words or so of an html article (in our case a blog post).

thx
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stackoverflow uses Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/case-studies/).

Elasticsearch has a [highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html)-features that take care of these things.

The snippet is determined search time, to find the snippet that is most likely to be relevant for the user's query.

Comment: Thx.  And is the meta tag "description" then also determined using Elastic search ? On all pages there is a meta tag "description" and this one is also filled with a snippet; but this time you have no search keywords ...

Comment: No. You'll have to determine that before submitting the document to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thx. So we will have to create our "own" "abstract/snippet/description" algorithm ?  Any idea whether this exists somewhere ?  Or should we not care about the meta tag description since in search results Elastic search provides the search snippet and in a Google search, Google is doing the same ?  So what is the purpose of meta tag description ...  Welcome your feedback.